# Neo4j ImpermanentDatabase in python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, neo4j

I am trying to create unit tests for a python project that will interface with a Neo4j Graph database.

Currently, I am implementing the embedded graph database, but will likely migrate to a REST interface if I choose to deploy this to a web application. 
I have intstalled v1.9rc2 of the embedded neo4j [project](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/python-embedded), installed via `pip` on a virtual environment.

There are mentionings of a java class `org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory`, [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.4/community/embedded-examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/Neo4jBasicDocTest.java), which sounds perfect for what I have in mind.   I am currently reading and writing to a database on file, which is ok, but I am having trouble properly cleaning up after ech test that doesn't include a call to `shutil.rmtree` ... or is that how it should be done?

Another possible method is to create and shutdown the database for each test, via the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods of my `TestCase`.

```
>>> import neo4j
>>> print neo4j.__version__
'1.9.c2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to create and shutdown the database individually for each test using setUp/tearDown - exactly as you've mentioned.

side note: 1.9rc2 is rather outdated, consider upgrading to latest stable since couple of bugs have been fixed since then.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my python bindings and see if any quirks get resolved. I wanted to avoid the time cost of setting up and shutting down the DB on each test, but if this is the only way to ensure proper clean up, then so be it

Comment: Getting build errors while trying to build the latest repo from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/python-embedded.  Errors here http://pastebin.com/CBr2XXqQ generated by calling `mvn -e package`.  This is my first time trying to build a project using maven, but Seems as though maven is looking for the neo4j jars at http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/everything/ but is unable to find them.  Any ideas?

Comment: regarding your 1st comment: using `TestGraphDatabaseFactory.newImpermanentDatabase()` is rather cheap. The big advantage is that you are to have a clean seperation between tests. I've seen to often tests that interfer with each other with is poison for maintainability of your code base.

Comment: regarding 2nd comment: try a `mvn install`. In case of issues, let's continue discussion on this in separate a thread here.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, my question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664352)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way they do it at the official Python Neo4j Driver, it should probably be considered "a good example" considering where it's coming from.

```
class ServerTestCase(TestCase):
""" Base class for test cases that use a remote server.
"""

known_hosts = KNOWN_HOSTS
known_hosts_backup = known_hosts + ".backup"

def setUp(self):
    if isfile(self.known_hosts):
        if isfile(self.known_hosts_backup):
            remove(self.known_hosts_backup)
        rename(self.known_hosts, self.known_hosts_backup)

def tearDown(self):
    if isfile(self.known_hosts_backup):
        if isfile(self.known_hosts):
            remove(self.known_hosts)
        rename(self.known_hosts_backup, self.known_hosts)
```

Here's the full source file: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/1.1/test/util.py

Comment: Since this comment was made, that code has moved, but it's still in the repo albeit under a different name. You can find it as `IntegrationTestCase` in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/1.6/test/integration/tools.py .