# Maven build error - neo4j-embedded python

Tags: python, maven, neo4j

I'm attempting to build the latest Embedded Neo4j Python bindings, cloned from  https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/python-embedded.git.  This is my first attempt at building a project using Maven, so I could just be missing something simple.

Reading the project docs, I ran `mvn package` which led to dependency errors, the verbose output is pasted here, http://pastebin.com/CBr2XXqQ

Some advice led me to try `mvn install` which seemed to download some dependency POM files, yet there is still a build error, citing an unresolved artifact for `org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:1.9-SNAPSHOT, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:1.9-SNAPSHOT`, http://pastebin.com/cGLNWnxU

Can someone shed some light on how to best resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with this particular project, but I have worked with Maven in the past.  I notice that the 1.9-SNAPSHOT version of neo4j is no longer available.  Try this: in the root of the source tree, find the file pom.xml.  Change the following line:

```
<neo4j.version>1.9-SNAPSHOT</neo4j.version>
```

to this:

```
<neo4j.version>1.9</neo4j.version>
```

And run "mvn install" again.  Hopefully there won't be any compatibility issues between the snapshots and release of version 1.9.